# How can I toggle styles (background-color to be specific) on multiple buttons with the same class (react.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I have multiple setting buttons and I need them to individually toggle their background colors

here's a simplified jsx example

```
   function App() {
      const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

      document.querySelectorAll('.setting-tile').forEach(el => 
               el.addEventListener('click', setToggle(!toggle)));

      return (
       <div className='container'>
         <button className={`settings ${toggle? 'change-color' : ''}`}</button>

         <button className={`settings ${toggle? 'change-color' : ''}`}</button>

         <button className={`settings ${toggle? 'change-color' : ''}`}</button>

         <button className={`settings ${toggle? 'change-color' : ''}`}</button>
       </div>
      )
   }
```

CSS

```
.settings {
    background-color: white;
} 
.change-color {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

but of course this won't work because the style would be applied to all the buttons at once.

How can I identify which one is clicked and style that specific button without having to create states and event listeners for all the buttons?

Edit - In case this wasn't clear, I'd like to be able to toggle all the buttons independently of each other.

Comment: AFAIK this would not be the "React" way of doing things ... you can have state for it and update when clicked ...

Comment: You could abstract the logic for button in a separate component. Instead of handling event listeners and multiple states or an array of state values you just have to handle one component. And call it any number of time from your parent component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something as below ... most of it is self explanatory

```js
const {useState} = React;

function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");
  
  const handleClick = (name) => {
    setSelected(name)
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Button name="one" selected={selected} onClick={handleClick}/>
      <Button name="two" selected={selected} onClick={handleClick}/>
      <Button name="three" selected={selected} onClick={handleClick}/>
      <Button name="four" selected={selected} onClick={handleClick}/>
    </div>
  );
}

function Button({name, onClick, selected}){
  return <button onClick={()=>onClick(name)} className={`settings ${name===selected ? "change-color" : ""}`}>{name}</button>
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App/>
);
```

```css
.settings {
    background-color: white;
} 
.change-color {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

---

As per the comment below - ***one button toggle doesn't un-toggle the other***

```js
const {useState} = React;

function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState({
    one : false,
    two : false,
    three : false,
    four : false
  });
  
  const handleClick = (name, isSelected) => {
    setSelected(prev=>({...prev,[name]: !isSelected}))
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {Object.entries(selected).map(([btn, isSelected])=>(
        <Button key={btn} name={btn} isSelected={isSelected} onClick={handleClick}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function Button({name, onClick, isSelected}){
  return <button onClick={()=>onClick(name, isSelected)} className={`settings ${isSelected ? "change-color" : ""}`}>{name}</button>
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App/>
);
```

```css
.settings {
    background-color: white;
} 
.change-color {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: "Would love to know better ways if any..." You should check out Code Review on the StackExchange

Comment: Interesting solution mate!
but like I said, I wanted them to be individually togglable. That is, only the clicked button should change color. Would love to see if you have a solution for that too.

Comment: sure @ControlAltDel ... I meant if I can see in other answers... But yeah makes sense

Comment: @Estif sorry, isn't it doing the same  ..

Comment: @KcH let me clarify, I meant multiple buttons should be togglable at once but not affect each other. Meaning one button toggle doesn't un-toggle the others.

Comment: @Estif edited answer, do you mean the same ?